# How do I get NMR signal integrals from TopSpin into R?

Tags: r

I use TopSpin (Bruker) for the processing of NMR spectra (phasing, peak picking and integration) but I want to process the obtained data further in R. For this, I specifically want to get the signal integration values (= peak areas) from TopSpin into R. I managed to export the spectral data as a JCAMP file (.dx) from TopSpin and to load this file in R, using the ReadJDX pacakage (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readJDX/index.html) but I can't find the integration info within the JCAMP file. Can anybody tell me if/where signal integration is stored within an NMR JCAMP file? Or, alternatively, any method to get an integrated NMR spectrum from TopSpin into R?

Processed a 1D 1H-NMR manually in TopSpin (manual peak picking, manual integration)
Saved spectrum as JCAMP-DX file: Save As - Save data set in JCAMP-DX file (Type of archive file: JCAMP FIX; Include data types: RSPEC+ISPEC; JCAMP version 6.0)
Loaded JCAMP file in R using
spectrum<-readJDX("jcampfile")
This results in a dataframe, containing both the real and imaginary parts of the spectrum as lists from which a spectrum can be plot. But I can't find the signal integrals as made in TopSpin.

Comment: To get datas et NMR spectrum I use https://github.com/INRA/NMRProcFlow (which call https://github.com/INRA/Rnmr1D). I use also https://github.com/sipss/AlpsNMR

Comment: I am not chemist. You want like anybody work with 1r spectrum, not fid spectrum (before FFT) ?